# Stretching a portion of a UIView using contentStretch

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uiview

I need some help understanding the use of the contentStretch property on a UIView.  I'd appreciate 1) some guidance on how to achieve the effect I'm going for and 2) a reference to any comprehensive documentation that exists on how to use this property.  While I thought I understood the Apple documentation, I now see that I don't.  Here is what I'm trying to do.

I have a custom UIView that renders a view that looks like figure a. below.  The drawRect method of this UIView paints the inner box on the left (with the rounded corners and white background) with a different color and affect than is used for the rest of the view.  Also, the 4 corners of the UIView are not stretchable (this would result in distortion) so I need to stretch only the center of the UIView background.

I want to grow this view to a shape similar to that pictured in figure b. below.  In doing so I want only the portion of the view outside the white box (or to the right of the white box) to be stretched/repeated as I increase the UIView's height.

[image: sketch1]

In all of my attempts I have only been able to produce a strecth that affects the entire width of the view and results in a view similar to figure c.

[image: sketch2]

Is it possible for me to achieve the effect that I want (figure b.) using contentStretch?  Is there some other technique I should be using short of re-drawing the entire view, or is re-drawing the only (or best) way to go about this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this happen with `contentStretch`, you would have to set the `contentStretch` rectangle so that its *top* edge is *below* the bottom edge of the white box, and so that its *left* edge is to the *right* of the right edge of the white box.  You will probably find that your background pattern gets stretched too much and looks ugly.

Instead, give your view a subview that draws just the white box.  Set the subview's springs and struts so that the box stays at the upper left and doesn't stretch.

Comment: The figures above are a bit misleading.  They are just a simplified wireframe of my actual view (for illustration purposes).  In my actual view the white box is a transparent (alpha = 0) window, so I don't know a way to make it a subview and still have it act like a window onto the background.  As for setting the contentStretch rectangle to be below and to the right of the white box, (which is what I feared I would have to attempt) I don't have enough space to do this because the region below the white box is in a non stretchable area (stretching it results in distortion of the background).

Comment: In that case, just use `UIViewContentModeRedraw` and draw what you need in `drawRect:`.

Comment: That's what I feared, but also what I expected.  Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I would make the white box stretchable on top, and a background view filled with a pattern using colorWithPatternImage:

```
patternView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:@"myBackgroundPattern.png"];
```

and the black stroke could be done with:

```
#include <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
...
patternView.layer.borderWidth = 2.f;
patternView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve can be done using the resizableImageWithCapInsets method of a UIImage. This way, you can set cap widths on each side of the image and specify which part of the image needs to be repeated (not stretched).

An UIEdgeInset is a struct consisting of four components as follows (CGFloat topCapWith, CGFloat leftCapWith, CGFloat bottomCapWith, CGFloat rightCapWith)

The code below would do the trick

```
UIImage * backgroundImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"Stretch.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(80, 4, 4, 10)];
    backgroundImageView.image = backgroundImage;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since content stretch is deprecated, best approach is to use auto layout. In the inner rectangle give a defining height and width constant and bind its top and leading constraints to the parent view. 
In order to get a bottom growth in outer rectangle, bind its bottom constraint or alternatively you can also chnage it height.